# Is there a way to have to placeholder label rendered at the top from the beginning

Tags: cosmicmind

Is there a way for the placeholder label of TextField to be rendered at the top from the beginning?

I don't want it to be animated when I focus on the textfield and it's empty.

Comment: This would be a great feature request :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use version [2.1.0](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.1.0), you can set the TextField's `isPlaceholderAnimated` property to `false`. That should give you the desired effect.

For example

```
let textField = TextField()
textField.isPlaceholderAnimated = false
```

:)